# I am trying to install psycopg2-binary in windows and getting warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, docker, psycopg2

I am trying to install psycopg2-binary in windows
I get this warning.
how can I solve this problem ??

```
PS C:\Users\zakoo> pip install psycopg2-binary                                                                          WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2-binary in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (2.8.6)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
```

when I run `docker-compose up` I get this error.

```
web_1  |     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
web_1  |     return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
web_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 29, in <module>
web_1  |     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)     
web_1  | django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

Comment: you should install psycopg2 inside of your docker container

Comment: @iklinac how do we do this? As I have the same problem!

Comment: What image are you using in your docker compose file?

Answer (score 0):

Two things seem to be happening here. In the first block of code, it looks like you're installing `psycopg2-binary` locally.

However, you then mention that you ran `docker-compose up` and the screenshot shows that `psycopg2` is missing in your `web_1` container.

I'm assuming that you have a `requirements.txt` which your `Dockerfile` is copying and installing from. Ensure that `psycopg2` is added to your `requirements.txt`.

In a nutshell, you've installed `psycopg2-binary` locally, but the error is coming from your container where `psycopg2`/`psycopg2-binary` hasn't been installed.